# FileListBox does not show files with known extensions hidden in Windows Explorer

Tags: vb6

I have a problem with the option "Hide extensions of known files" in Windows Explorer and Visual Basic 6, specifically with the FileListBox component.

The problem has happened to me when installing in a couple of clients a program that, among other things, shows * .mp3 files of a directory through a FileListBox. The fact is that the list of files appeared empty, when there really were mp3 files in the corresponding directory.

In order for them to appear, I had to close the program and uncheck the check "Hide extensions of known files" in their Windows Explorer settings, which I do not really like having to do. In both cases it was a Windows 7.

I tried to render the case on my computer, also with Windows 7, in Windows 10 and Windows XP but although I have activated the check "Hide extensions of known files", in my case they do appear, which also I am a bit limited to when correcting this behavior.

What explanation can all this have? How can I ensure for future installations that I show the files in FileListBox even if the client has activated the check "Hide extensions of known files"?

Comment: Assign the FileListBox's `Hiidden` property to `True`?

Comment: Er, `Hidden` - sorry.

Comment: Thank you @Bob77, when I can reproduce the error I'll prove it and I'll tell you

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn´t work for me. Everything remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

The FileListBox is an ancient control, dating back to the old Windows 3.1 days (pre-Windows 95). In those days, there wasn't the option of hiding file extensions. So FileListBox doesn't work properly with hidden file extensions, as you have found.

If you want the functionality you're looking for, consider using he FileSystemObject library to get the files you're looking for, and displaying them in an ordinary ListBox. If you go to the trouble of doing this, you'll have a lot more flexibility in defining solutions for your clients.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn´t work for me. Everything remains the same.

Comment: @JosMarRivera If you want help on a FileSystemObject solution that doesn't work for you, then you might want to post a new question with a more specific explanation of the problems you're encountering.